# How to pause the Jmeter run in non gui mode in linux server

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am posting data to a REST API using HTTP POST requests. The jmeter setup is single thread. As i am making 200,000 post calls i want to pause the run when needed and i want to resume the run when needed.

```js
NOTE: i am running the jmeter in NON GUI mode on Linux server, which will not have a GUI for anything.
Other important thing is i can't program it before the run starts because i'm not sure when to pause the suit or when to resume it.
```

Answer (score 2):

JMeter-specific solution would be using [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) and [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) combination.

1. Add Constant Throughput Timer to your test plan and set your desired throughput in requests per minute. If you don't want to limit JMeter - set it to something very high using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

   ```
   ${__P(throughput,10000000)}
   ```
2. Enable Beanshell Server by adding the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   beanshell.server.port=9000
   beanshell.server.file=../extras/startup.bsh
   ```
3. Create 2 scripts like

   - `suspend.bsh` containing  the next line:

     ```
     setprop(throughput, 0);
     ```
   - and `resume.bsh` containing the next line:

     ```
     setprop(throughput, 10000000);
     ```

   Whenever you need to suspend your test invoke the following command from "lib" folder of your JMeter installation:

   ```
   java -jar bshclient.jar localhost 9000 /path/to/your/suspend.bsh
   ```

Chwck out [How to Change JMeter´s Load During Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime) article for more details.

---

Linux specific solution would be using [`kill` command](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html) like:

- to suspend: `kill -SIGSTOP JMETER_JAVA_PID`
- to continue: `kill -SIGCONT JMETER_JAVA_PID`

where `JMETER_JAVA_PID` is process id of the JVM which is running JMeter, you can find this out using [`jps` command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html)